# Is there an alternative to the -noverify jvm flag?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, verification

I have a runnable .jar application that I am running on a server, but I don't have access to the startup script (java -jar myapplication.jar).  I require use of the noverify flag but I don't know if I can set that since I cannot use that startup script.  Is there an alternative to still disable java bytecode verification?

Comment: Why would you want to disable verification?

Comment: Is It due to speed or bad byte code you need this?

Comment: Some classes are only loaded on the first time they are needed, so I get lots of classnotfound exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can wirte another startup script like this:

```
java -Xverify:none -jar myapplication.jar
```